# C++ defining IAT manually

Tags: gcc

I just changed from (F)ASM to C and saw that I get for a MessageBox 25kb (vs 3kb). I just included windows.h, but I see that windows.h includes about 22kb that I don't need ;).
At ASM I'm able to define the IAT (Import Address Table) and this I want to do with the GCC to reduce the oversized executable.
SO does anyone know how I can do this? Is it possible?

PS: If you know a solution for an other compiler please post it too (then I'll use the other one).

Answer (score 0):

OK because I can't find any way to do it, I read about shell code (which has to be small and position independend).
harmonysecurity.com wrote about this and so I would solve my problem with inline-ASM.
[This is the blog.](http://blog.harmonysecurity.com/2009/08/calling-api-functions.html)
I hope that helps.